# Why is Roboto not available on Chrome for Android?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I used this script (https://www.samclarke.com/2013/06/javascript-is-font-available/) to check if `Roboto` is available on my devices.

I found 2 interesting things:

1. As I have `Roboto` installed as font on my Windows desktop pc, the script says the font is available. Also, trying to use it as `font-family`, works without requesting it from google fonts.
2. On my 5.1 Android phone, the script says that Roboto is not available by default, and if trying to set it as `font-family: Roboto, Times;` without using google fonts, Times shows up.

This surprises me as Roboto is the default font for New Android OS versions so I wonder if I am making any mistake or, as this is nonsense, why did they decide not to include this for native browser use.

Check it here:

```css
.roboto {
  font-family: "Roboto", Times;
}
```

```html
<p class="roboto">Is this Roboto?</p>
```

Comment: what do u mean by doesn't have any effect. text changed to roboto or just sans serif

Comment: @NirpendraPatel if you have `font-family: Roboto, Times;` Times shows up.

Comment: can u try  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;